# How to communicate Between two lightning pages(AURA)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have two different lightning Pages A B. On clicking a button on page A I need to pass a parameter to page B which can render based on the passed parameter. Can anyone suggest to me how to do it??

FYI,
I tried LocalStorage, sessionStorage but no luck. Even tried setting cookies but the value is not getting stored, getting null when reading the cookie on other the page. Tried to pass the Parameter in the URL but the URL gets replaced when the component renders. Events not working two different Apps/Pages.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the relationship between the two pages?

Comment: one is a Queue page, and the other is a detail page for each record present in the queue

Comment: It sounds like you might need lightning:empApi in order to communicate across the two pages.

Comment: passing query parameters in URL worked fine, I forgot to add c__ namespace infront of the attribute which was replacing my parameters everytime URL loads.

Comment: @sfdxfox thanks for your quick response